# Create an event handler for the submit button

Tags: python, flask

I want to make an event handler for the button, which will change the background color.

This my code

**HTML**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Flask Tutorial</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1> My First Try Using Flask </h1>
        <p> Flask is Fun </p>
         <form method="post">
        <input  type="submit" name="red" value ="red" >
         </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**Flask**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def home():
    red  = request.form("background-color:red;")
    return render_template("home.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

How do I set an even handler for a button click in Flask?

Answer (score 0):

So this is a simple event handler written in flask.

The index.html(your code with action attribute for form):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Flask Tutorial</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> My First Try Using Flask </h1>
    <p> Flask is Fun </p>
     <form action="/action" method="POST">
    <input  type="submit" name="red" value ="red" >
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then the action is a another html page which is like an event handler.
action.html:

```
<html> <p> Button color is {{ red }} </p> </html>
```

And the flask code to handle the events is below:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import os

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=os.getcwd())
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/action", methods = ['POST'])
def action():
    red = request.form.get('red')
    return render_template('action.html', red=red)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have problem. When I start the application and click on the button, error 404 appears.When i run the address http://localhost:*numbers*/webtry/index.html?_ijt=8jd7df7h12jqlppr2c6jc0uja9.  If i click button http://localhost:*numbers*/action.  May be you know how fix it. And if i run action.html i see only text Button color is {{ red }}. But not red background

Comment: You need to run as http://localhost:5000/ and you will have the code working. Then click on the button and you will see everything working fine

Comment: Python 3.7.1 IDE Pycharm 2018.2.4 , flask 1.0.2

Comment: Can you paste the log that you see when you run the code? I ran this code using Pycharm only.

Comment: If you need to change the background of the page when clicking a button then you can use javascript you don't need flask for it. I gave this answer as an event handler when you submit the form.

Comment: Okay. May I ask how to do it? And how fix error 404

Comment: After starting the app just visit http://localhost:numbers/ and nothing else. And place the flask app and the html files in the same folder not separate

Comment: Can you paste the pycharm log output? Mine is something like this                
 * Serving Flask app "sample_file" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 270-502-007
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Comment: Whern i wrote in console "Flask run" - it worked. About your comment "If you need to change the background of the page when clicking a button then you can use javascript you don't need flask for it. "  On assignment, I have to create a web application in Python that will change the background color at the touch of a button. And from the example in C # I decided to go through the flask

Comment: Maybe can I give a better idea. If you have get request you get one template and if you click button you get same page in different color. Its like for GET request one color and POST request one color

Comment: Do you suggest something to create a color change using javascript and link to different pages? I understood correctly?

Comment: You can do it in flask by using different templates, one without any colors and another template to catch the post request and change the background color

Comment: I understood. I'll try your idea

Comment: Like just add css styling to the action.html and you are good to go

Comment: What happened? Did you try anything and what was the output?

Comment: How can I write to you, not to breed flooding here?